# Creating report and inserting comma at end of it in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, reports

When I run a create report and want to use the comma when you want to sum the acres ? Is there a way around to do that ?

Here is the attachment where I use the yellow highlight.

[image: See here]

It is so much easier if you just add the comma !

I am using ArcGIS ArcMap 10.0 SP4.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  I'm not sure where a comma would come into play here.

Comment: Can you see the picture I have highlight ? There is no comma it is just all numbers with a decimal. So my question is how to I add the comma like this 1,098,021.647919  ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can decide to include the commas as part of the report creation process.

However, if you go to the **Fields** tab of the **Properties** for the Layer containing **SUM_ACRES** then its **Appearance** includes **Number Format** set to **Numeric**.  Hit the **...** button and you will be able to tick the checkbox for **Show thousands separators**.

Once the field has the right appearance (showing thousands separators) the report you run using it will also.